# WiFi managerからRSSIの値を取得する方法

Tags: android

WifiのRSSIを取得したく存じます。
下記のように記述しましたが、RSSIの値が取得できておりません。
修正方法をご教示願えませんでしょうか。

```
// 信号強度の取得部分。
private double getStrength() {
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
    String[] apInfo = new String[4];
    int rssi = info .getRssi();
    int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(rssi, 5);
    apInfo[3] = String.format("RSSI : %d / Level : %d/4", rssi, level);
    return rssi;
}
```

Comment: うまくいっていない状況をより具体的に (期待している動作と実際の動作を) 書くと、的確なアドバイスをもらいやすいと思います。回答者の側もいろいろな推測をせずに済みます。

Comment: 次回より期待動作なども記載するようにいたします。
ありがとうございます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。今回の質問についても、どういう値が返ってきていたのかを記載しておくと、後で同じ症状を検索した人により役立つ質問になると思いますよ。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

戻り値のdoubleをint型に変えて、出力した結果、この値でいいのか分かりませんがマイナス値(-55, -74...)が取れてました。ホームボタン押下、アプリをクリックを繰り返すと`onResume()`が呼ばれるのでそこでログに出してざっと確認しました。

そこで思ったのですが、AndroidManifest.xmlに次のパーミッションの設定を忘れていませんか。

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />`

あるいは、`wifiInfo`の取得にあたって、`Broadcast Receiver`の設定をしておけば[捗るのかもしれません。](http://android-er.blogspot.jp/2011/01/check-rssi-by-monitoring-of.html)
ちなみに、端末のwifiを飛行機モードにすると-127で固定になるので、wifiはONにしないと動かないと存じます。

試しに動かしたソースコードを下に一応置きます。

```
// Sample code.

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //　手元にあったプロジェクトを使ったので無視して下さい。   
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Log.v("tag","Pushed");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        Log.e("TAG", Integer.toString(getStrength()));
    }

    private int getStrength() {
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
        String[] apInfo = new String[4];
        int rssi = info .getRssi();
        int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(rssi, 5);
        apInfo[3] = String.format("RSSI : %d / Level : %d/4", rssi, level);
        return rssi;
    }   
}
```

追記:
マイナス値でいいみたいです。
`Relevant rssi range on android is between -100 and -55`が取得できるそうです。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275306/whats-the-meaning-of-rssi-in-android-wifimanager

-127の正体は`INVALID_RSSI`でした。
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/59701b9ba5c453e327bc0e6873a9f6ff87a10391/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.java#L403

以上、勉強させていただきました。

Comment: マニフェストへのパーミッションの設定が漏れていました。
また、getStrength() の呼び出しもうまくいっていなかったようです。

RSSIは-xxdBmなので、マイナス値で出るのですね。